# Gulp creates empty folder in dist for ignored directory

Tags: directory, gulp

I'm excluding the content of the directories in `gulp.src` using the `!` symbol, but the directories themselves are still included, for example:

```
gulp.src(["./src/**", "!./src/pages/**"], { base: "./src/" })
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/"))
```

outputs

```
dist ->
       pages
```

but I don't want the directory pages. Any idea?

Comment: what is this `{ base: "./src/" }`

Comment: do you want to ignore `./src/pages/**`  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude the directory explicitly:

```
gulp.src(["./src/**", "!./src/pages", "!./src/pages/**"], { base: "./src/" })
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/"))
```

Alternatively you can also use [brace expansion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#glob-primer):

```
gulp.src(["./src/**", "!./src/pages{/**,}"], { base: "./src/" })
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/"))
```